# How to add .bundle to Xcode 4 source control?

Tags: ios, xcode, version-control, xcode4

There is a question mark next to a `.bundle` file in a Xcode 4.3 project:

[image]

When I try to right-click and select `Source Control`, the `Add` menuitem is disabled/dimmed:

[image]

How can I add the `.bundle` to source control?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For stuff like this that Xcode doesn't instinctively or decently do, I usually resort to using the command line options.

For a whole directory such as a bundle, use Terminal to `cd` to the directory where the bundle lives and then do `svn add Settings.bundle` or `git add Settings.bundle` or whatever source control set-up you're using.

And once it's checked in or committed & pushed or whatever, Xcode will be able to manage the files within that directory just fine.

Comment: I was having the same problem but when I tried this, svn tell me the file is already under version control and I still have the question mark.

Comment: UPDATE: I needed to delete the .svn directory from that .bundle directory and re-commit.